# progress bar in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to start my progress bar and after the data is loaded to i stop it. The problem is how I could stop it from another class in Windows phone

This is my first class I declared the progress bar in the XAML:

```
 public class panorama
    {
        progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
        progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        App.PanoramaViewModel.LoadData();
    }
```

and this is my second class

```
  public class panoramaviewmodel 
    {
        public void LoadData()
        {
        }
    }
```

I like stop progress bar in the `panoramaviewmodel`. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `Visibility` on the control either to a `Visibility` or to a `bool` property in your `ViewModel`. Make sure that the `ViewModel` implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The moment you will change the property in the `ViewModel` to be collapsed (or `false`, if you choose to use `bool` through a converter), the control that is bound to it will update as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `panorama` class you refer to is the view (page) you have a few options:

1. Add a property to the viewmodel that indicates whether the progressbar should show an indeterminate state and then bind to that. (This is the most common approach taken in WP apps.)
2. Have the viewmodel send a message, to indicate the change is status, that the view is listening for and responds to accordingly.
3. Add an event to the view model that is fired when the loading indicator should be changed and have the page subscribe to it and update the indicator accordingly.
4. Pass a reference to the progress bar to the viewmodel and have it update the progressbar directly when appropriate. (I'm just including this for completion and this is last on the list for a reason. This breaks the separation that is one of the aims/benefits of MVVM)

As the `ProgressBar` takes up space on the page I'd also recommend against altering the Visibility as well as changing the `IsIndeterminite` property. By always having it visible (but varying the `IsIndeterminite` state) you'll avoid unnecessary changes to the visual tree (and the recalculations that involves) and potentially avoid other elements on the page from moving in response to collapsing the ProgressBar.